# Ionic 2: Error installing Google Maps plugin

Tags: google-maps, cordova, ionic2, cordova-plugins, angular2-services

I'm trying to install this plugin for Google Maps: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/google-maps/ but have an error:

> Error: Failed to fetch plugin https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps-sdk via registry.
>   Probably this is either a connection problem, or plugin spec is incorrect.
>   Check your connection and plugin name/version/URL.
>   Error: npm: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
>   npm ERR! code 1

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$> git clone  https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps-sdk

$> cd (path to your project)

$> cordova plugin add (path to)/cordova-plugin-googlemaps-sdk
```